# Simplify is excluding indeterminate expression from output

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Consider the following code and its output:

```
Simplify[Sin[n Pi]/n, Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]
```

> ```
> (* 0 *)
> ```

However when I try

```
Simplify[Sin[n Pi]/n, Assumptions -> n == 0]
```

> Simplify::infd: Expression Sin[n Pi]/n simplified to Indeterminate.
>
> ```
> Indeterminate
> ```

I am wondering why didn't Simplify included the separate case n=0 in the first output, and how to avoid this type of errors.

Comment: In a pre-calclulus book I once used, an algebraic identity was an equation which is true for all values of the variables for which both sides are defined.  That's less restrictive than saying they are identical as functions.  `Simplify` seems to take the less restrictive approach.

Comment: Related: [(65624)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65624), [(66166)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66166), [(89990)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89990)

Answer (score 6):

The `Possible Issues` section of the documentation for [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) states: "The Wolfram Language evaluates zero times a symbolic expression to zero ... Because of this, results of simplification of expressions with singularities are uncertain."

For the case, `n==0` you need to take the [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html)

```
Limit[Sin[n Pi]/n, n -> 0]

(*  π  *)
```

A [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) shows that this `Limit` is consistent

```
Plot[Sin[n Pi]/n, {n, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Sin[n Pi]/n == Pi Sin[n Pi]/(n Pi) == Pi Sinc[n Pi] // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)

FullSimplify[Pi Sinc[n Pi], Element[n, Integers]]

(*  π KroneckerDelta[n]  *)

% // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Reduce` is usually careful, compared with `Simplify` or `Solve`. (Note that the desired result, here represented by `ConditionalExpression`, is not really "simpler" in the usual [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html)/ [`` Simplify`SimplifyCount ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84950/4999) sense used by `Simplify`.)  One oddity is the mathematically redundant `n == 0` in the condition `Element[n, Integers] || n == 0` makes a difference: The case `n == 0` is not overlooked as it is with just `Element[n, Integers]`.  This is true for `Simplify[Sin[n Pi]/n, Element[n, Integers] || n == 0]`, too, although it returns `Sin[n Pi]/n`.

Here is the result of `Reduce`, set up to work like `Simplify`:

```
x /. First@Solve[Reduce[(Element[n, Integers] || n == 0) && x == Sin[n Pi]/n], x]
(*  ConditionalExpression[0, (n ∈ Integers && n >= 1) || (n ∈ Integers && n <= -1)]  *)
```

Note it returns `Undefined`, as it should as a function of an integer variable, if `0` is subsituted for `n`:

```
% /. n -> 0
(*  Undefined  *)
```